# How can I make my card view littile circular in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
//
```

In below code I am trying to make on ui according to my ux design . But One problem i am facing is not able to make card like same in ux , in ux its someting circular ,but in my code its not coming. It tried with border radius also . Please suggest where I am wrong [image]
[image: this is the design]

```
 <View style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5, borderRadius: 2, padding: 10 }} >
                      <Card >
                        <CardItem header style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff', width: '100%', justifyContent: 'space-between', borderBottomColor: '#f1f1f1', borderBottomWidth: 1,borderRadius: 80 }}>
                          <View style={{paddingTop:10 }}>
                              <RegularText text={`${'Wallet Balance'}`} textColor='grey'style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', flexWrap: 'wrap',color:'grey' }} />
                          </View>

                            <View style = {{ width : wp('10%'),height: wp('10%'),backgroundColor : '#E091C9' ,borderRadius : hp('1%'), margin : 8,flexDirection :'row',justifyContent :'center',alignItems : 'center'}}>
                           <SvgCss xml={WALLET} width={15} height={15} />
                             </View>

                            <View style={{
                            flexDirection: 'column',
                            height: 25, paddingRight: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingTop: 5,paddingBottom:30}}>
                            <SmallText text={'MUR 110.00'} textColor='red' />
                            <SmallText text={'Add Money'} textColor='blue' />
                            </View>

                        </CardItem>
                        <View style = {{flexDirection : 'row',paddingLeft:24,paddingRight:24}}>
                        {info.tecnologies.map(
                          (data, index) => {
                              return (
                                <View>
                                  <View style = {{width : wp('14%'),height: wp('14%'),backgroundColor : 'rgb(163, 153, 233)',borderRadius : hp('2%'), margin : 10,flexDirection :'row',justifyContent :'center',alignItems : 'center'}}>
                                <SvgCss xml={PAY_BILL} width={15} height={15} />
                                  </View>
                                  <View style={{paddingLeft:15,paddingBottom:15}}>
                                  <SmallText text={'Pay Bill'} textColor='grey' />

                                  </View>
                                </View>
                              )
                          }
                      )}
                      </View>
                      </Card>
                    </View>
```

[image: left side is ux and right side is what i am doing ..]

Comment: you can use `borderRadius`

Comment: try borderRadius:50 in top view component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this :

```
<View style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5, borderRadius: 2, padding: 10 }} >
                      <Card style={{ borderRadius: 8 }}>
                        <CardItem header style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff', width: '100%', justifyContent: 'space-between', borderBottomColor: '#f1f1f1', borderBottomWidth: 1,borderRadius: 80 }}>
                          <View style={{paddingTop:10 }}>
                              <RegularText text={`${'Wallet Balance'}`} textColor='grey'style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', flexWrap: 'wrap',color:'grey' }} />
                          </View>

                            <View style = {{ width : wp('10%'),height: wp('10%'),backgroundColor : '#E091C9' ,borderRadius : hp('1%'), margin : 8,flexDirection :'row',justifyContent :'center',alignItems : 'center'}}>
                           <SvgCss xml={WALLET} width={15} height={15} />
                             </View>

                            <View style={{
                            flexDirection: 'column',
                            height: 25, paddingRight: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingTop: 5,paddingBottom:30}}>
                            <SmallText text={'MUR 110.00'} textColor='red' />
                            <SmallText text={'Add Money'} textColor='blue' />
                            </View>

                        </CardItem>
                        <View style = {{flexDirection : 'row',paddingLeft:24,paddingRight:24}}>
                        {info.tecnologies.map(
                          (data, index) => {
                              return (
                                <View>
                                  <View style = {{width : wp('14%'),height: wp('14%'),backgroundColor : 'rgb(163, 153, 233)',borderRadius : hp('2%'), margin : 10,flexDirection :'row',justifyContent :'center',alignItems : 'center'}}>
                                <SvgCss xml={PAY_BILL} width={15} height={15} />
                                  </View>
                                  <View style={{paddingLeft:15,paddingBottom:15}}>
                                  <SmallText text={'Pay Bill'} textColor='grey' />

                                  </View>
                                </View>
                              )
                          }
                      )}
                      </View>
                      </Card>
                    </View>
```

Comment: Thanks ... one help can you please.. in carditeam there is wallet balance then there is icon wallet and then Add Money' and Mur 100 .. its not comig properly

Answer (score 1):

For your another question :

```
<View style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5, borderRadius: 2, padding: 10 }} >
                      <Card style={{ borderRadius: 8 }}>
                        <CardItem header style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff', width: '100%', justifyContent: 'space-between', borderBottomColor: '#f1f1f1', borderBottomWidth: 1,borderRadius: 80 }}>
                          <View style={{paddingTop:10 }}>
                              <RegularText text={`${'Wallet Balance'}`} textColor='grey'style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', flexWrap: 'wrap',color:'grey' }} />
                          </View>

                            <View style = {{ width : wp('10%'),height: wp('10%'),backgroundColor : '#E091C9' ,borderRadius : hp('1%'), margin : 8,flexDirection :'row',justifyContent :'center',alignItems : 'center', alignSelf : 'flex-end'}}>
                           <SvgCss xml={WALLET} width={15} height={15} />

                <View style={{
                                flexDirection: 'column',
                                height: 25, paddingRight: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingTop: 5,paddingBottom:30}}>
                                <SmallText text={'MUR 110.00'} textColor='red' />
                                <SmallText text={'Add Money'} textColor='blue' />
                            </View>
                             </View>



                        </CardItem>
                        <View style = {{flexDirection : 'row',paddingLeft:24,paddingRight:24}}>
                        {info.tecnologies.map(
                          (data, index) => {
                              return (
                                <View>
                                  <View style = {{width : wp('14%'),height: wp('14%'),backgroundColor : 'rgb(163, 153, 233)',borderRadius : hp('2%'), margin : 10,flexDirection :'row',justifyContent :'center',alignItems : 'center'}}>
                                <SvgCss xml={PAY_BILL} width={15} height={15} />
                                  </View>
                                  <View style={{paddingLeft:15,paddingBottom:15}}>
                                  <SmallText text={'Pay Bill'} textColor='grey' />

                                  </View>
                                </View>
                              )
                          }
                      )}
                      </View>
                      </Card>
                    </View>
```

Comment: Explain what you have done here and don't just paste a bunch of code

Comment: I have just put the  column inside the second element of row and aligned that second element at right position

Comment: I mean you should explain what you have done, in the answer itself, not in the comments. Just a friendly advice how to make your answers a bit clearer :)